# Regexp_Replace in HIVE to keep only certain words

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to use regexp_replace in HIVE as a way to only keep certain words of a string.

I am trying to use the following:

`select regexp_replace('I AM WANTING BLUE SHOES AND YELLOW STRINGS', '([^BLUE|SHOES|YELLOW|STRINGS])',' ')`

But it is giving me "I W NTING BLUE SHOES N YELLOW STRINGS" instead of "BLUE SHOES YELLOW STRINGS"

I have tried using `\b` `\s` and any number of things to no avail.  Any tips on getting this to work?

I also considered using `regexp_replace` but for my particular use case there are too many variables for it to be useful.

Comment: Try `select regexp_replace('I AM WANTING BLUE SHOES AND YELLOW STRINGS', '\\s*\\b(?!(?:BLUE|SHOES|YELLOW|STRINGS)\\b)\\w+','')`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew!! That worked exactly like I was hoping.  Now I will just go about familiarizing myself with the elements of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select regexp_replace('I AM WANTING BLUE SHOES AND YELLOW STRINGS', '\\s*\\b(?!(?:BLUE|SHOES|YELLOW|STRINGS)\\b)\\w+','')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLS2uD/1)

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:BLUE|SHOES|YELLOW|STRINGS)\b)` - no `BLUE`, `SHOES`, `YELLOW` and `STRINGS` substring is allowed immediately on the right
- `\w+`  - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`)